# Map with values using different generic type parameters

Tags: java, generics, guava

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
  private static final ImmutableMap<String, List<?>> lists = ImmutableMap.of(
      "A", new ArrayList<String>(),
      "B", new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Essentially, the primary distinction I am trying to capture is that the different values have different type parameters.  However this gives the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
ImmutableMap<String,ArrayList<? extends Object&Serializable&Comparable<?>>>
to ImmutableMap<String,List<?>>
```

Is there a better way to do this or some way around this problem?

Comment: This works for me. Is it just the one line that doesn't work for you?

Comment: This works for you?  Yes, this is the only line that does not work.

Comment: Yes. I copy/pasted the exact line of code into my IDE. Which Java version are you using? I'm currently using `1.8.0_66`

Comment: I think this is the issue in a different question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143959/issue-creating-immutablemap-with-class-as-key
Changing to the builder pattern rather than using the of method resolved the issue.
Maybe this has already been fixed in a later version of the library than what I am using.

Comment: Could be. I'm using `guava-r09`

Comment: The main problem is that you're (obviously) using Java 7. For Java 8, the type inference was improved, and it is able to figure out the right type. For Java 7, you could simply use `ImmutableMap.<String, List<?>>of( ... )`  to pin the type to the desired one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code compiles fine in Java 1.8, but it fails to compile in Java 1.7.  Included in Java 1.8 is [improved target type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types).

Basically what this means is that in Java 1.7, the compiler will infer the most specific type of a generic type parameter possible, even if that will cause a compiler error with the target type (in this case, `ImmutableMap<String, List<?>>`).

In Java 1.8, the target type is taken into account, such that the type parameter of the map's value is taken to be `List<?>` instead of `ArrayList<? extends Object&Serializable&Comparable<?>>`.

You can either upgrade to Java 1.8, or you can supply an explicit type parameter to the call to [the `of` method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of(K,%20V,%20K,%20V)).

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, List<?>> lists =
     //           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
     ImmutableMap.<String, List<?>>of(
          "A", new ArrayList<String>(),
          "B", new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but this is the general concept that I believe you want:

```
private ImmutableMap<String, List<T extends Object&Serializable&Configurable<?>>> = ...;
```

You can't do it with wildcards, but can with named types. So you may need to declare the type at class level instead of field level, but then you can use your declared type in the normal manner.